# Using ARKit to detect Face moving direction (Top, Left. Bottom, Right)

Tags: swift, ios11, arkit, face-detection

I am working on `ARFaceTrackingConfiguration` to detect face and which I have achieved easily using `Vision` framework. Now, I want to detect whether user is looking "Left - Right - Top - Bottom" and based on that I need to do show something on screen. But the problem is I cannot able to detect how to do so!

What I have tried so far?

```
extension FaceDetectionViewController: ARSCNViewDelegate {
    //implement ARSCNViewDelegate functions for things like error tracking
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
        scanForFaces()
        if let faceAnchor = anchor as? ARFaceAnchor {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                //This changes as I move camera and cannot able to detect logic
                let position = faceAnchor.transform.position()
                self.lblX.text = "X: \(node.position.x)----Y: \(node.position.y)"
                self.lblY.text = "X: \(position.x)----Y: \(position.y)"
            }
        }
        //Same this problem appears here too
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.lblX.text = " \(node.eulerAngles.x) "
            self.lblY.text = " \(node.eulerAngles.y) "
        }
    }
}

extension matrix_float4x4 {
    func position() -> SCNVector3 {
        return SCNVector3(columns.3.x, columns.3.y, columns.3.z)
    }
}

@objc
private func doFaceScan() {

    //get the captured image of the ARSession's current frame
    guard let capturedImage = sceneView.session.currentFrame?.capturedImage else { return }
    let image = CIImage.init(cvPixelBuffer: capturedImage)

    let detectFaceRequest = VNDetectFaceRectanglesRequest { (request, error) in

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            //Loop through the resulting faces and add a red UIView on top of them.
            if let faces = request.results as? [VNFaceObservation] {
                for face in faces {
                    self.faceFrame(from: face.boundingBox)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    try? VNImageRequestHandler(ciImage: image, orientation: self.imageOrientation).perform([detectFaceRequest])
}
```

Can anyone pls help?

Comment: i am also looking for the same please help